# How to keep a draggable object in its original place after drop

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I have a small draggable/droppable jquery app and I am having trouble retaining the draggable item and keeping it in its original position once its clone has been dropped.

Can anyone assist?

http://jsfiddle.net/franco13/vLSZf/1/

Thank you.

```
$(init);

function init() {

    $('.teamEmblem').draggable({
        //    containment: $('.teamEmblem').parent(), // this does not work
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: 'clone',
        obstacle: ".teamEmblem", // this does not work
        preventCollision: true, // this does not work
        revert: true
    });

    $('.winner').droppable({
        hoverClass: 'hovered',
        tolerance: 'touch',
        drop: handleCardDrop1
    });

}

function handleCardDrop1(event, ui) {

    if (true) {
        ui.draggable.addClass('correct');
        ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
        $(this).droppable('disable');
        ui.draggable.position({
            of: $(this),
            my: 'left top',
            at: 'left top'
        });
        ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could clone the draggable element and apply little style to the cloned element:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vLSZf/4/)

```
function handleCardDrop1(event, ui) {
    if (true) {

        ui.draggable.addClass('correct');
        ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
        $(this).droppable('disable');

        var dragged = ui.draggable.clone(true);
        dragged.position({
            of: $(this),
            my: 'left top',
            at: 'left top'
        }).css({
            position: 'absolute',
            display: 'block',
            margin: '0 auto'
        });
        ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
        $('body').append(dragged);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks @roasted. (obviously) your jsfiddle worked. I will incorporate your code into my script and post back and accept this as the answer. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I have another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263164/how-to-replicate-a-draggable-droppable-instance-in-jquery-after-first-instance-c @roasted in case you like the challenge of solving jquery dragging and dropping. Thanks!